# no muestra N/A en el input

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter-4

queria ver si me pueden ayudar, estoy trabajando con code y js para las alertas pero estoy buscando la manera en que cuando en la parte del html $valor que trae una cadena regrese la cadena vacia en el input se coloque N/A pero por alguna razon no lo pone este es mi html

```
  <td class="text-lefth">Marcador inferior:</td>
                            <td class="text-lefth">S-AC-AC-01</td>
                            <td class="text-lefth">
                                <?php foreach ($detalles as $row1) {
                                    $hen1 = $row1['hendidos'];
                                    $hen = explode(",", $hen1);

                                    if (isset($hen[2])) { //esta parte hace una condicion 
                                        $valor = $hen[2];
                                    } else {
                                        $valor = "";
                                    }
                                ?>
                                    <span id="henValue"><?php echo $valor; ?></span> ± 3 mm
                                <?php } ?>
                            </td>
                            <input type="hidden" id="hen2" name="hen2" value="<?php echo $valor; ?>">

                            <td class="text-lefth">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MarcaInf3" name="MarcaInf3" maxlength="15" autocomplete="off" v-model="MarcaInf3" onkeypress="return validaNumericos(event)" >
                            </td>
```

y este es mi js y creo que tiene que ver porque como son validaciones siempre espera que este vacio

el: '#save',
data: {
errored: false,

```
    ECT3: '',
    Lartotal3: '',
    Anchtotal3: '',
    MarcaSuper3: '',
    MarcaInf3: '',
    Combado3: '',
    Sesame13: 'N/A',
    Sesame23: 'N/A',
    Sesame33: 'N/A',
    sta1: '',
    sta2: '',
    sta3: '',
    sta4: '',
    Oservaciones: '',
    certificado_guardado: '',
    
},
methods: {
    save(event) {
        let sigue;
        datos = new FormData();
        datos.append('certificado_calidad_norden', $("#norden1").val());
        datos.append('certificado_calidad_npedido', $("#npedido").val());
        datos.append('certificado_calidad_proveedor', $("#proveedor").val());
        datos.append('certificado_calidad_cliente', $("#cliente").val());
        datos.append('certificado_calidad_nmaterial', $("#nmaterial").val());
        datos.append('certificado_calidad_fecha_fabricacion', $("#ffabricacion").val());
        datos.append('certificado_calidad_simbolo', $("#simbolo").val()); 
        datos.append('certificado_calidad_ECT', this.ECT3);
        datos.append('certificado_calidad_largo_total', this.Lartotal3);
        datos.append('certificado_calidad_ancho_total', this.Anchtotal3);
        datos.append('certificado_calidad_marcador_superior', this.MarcaSuper3);
        datos.append('certificado_calidad_marcador_inferior', this.MarcaInf3);
        datos.append('certificado_calidad_combado', this.Combado3);
        datos.append('certificado_calidad_hilo1', this.Sesame13);
        datos.append('certificado_calidad_hilo2', this.Sesame23);
        datos.append('certificado_calidad_hilo3', this.Sesame33);
        datos.append('certificado_calidad_deslaminado', this.sta1);
        datos.append('certificado_calidad_desorillado', this.sta2);
        datos.append('certificado_calidad_apariencia_lamina', this.sta3);
        datos.append('certificado_calidad_prueba_bond', this.sta4);
        datos.append('certificado_calidad_observaciones', this.Oservaciones);
        datos.append('certificado_calidad_crear_usuarioid', $("#user").val());
        datos.append('certificado_guardado', $("#certificado_guardado").val());
        
        datos.append('boardName', $("#ECT").val());
        datos.append('largo', $("#la").val());
        datos.append('ancho', $("#an").val());
        datos.append('hendidos', $("#hen1").val());
        datos.append('hen2',$("#hen2").val());

        if (this.MarcaInf3 === 'N/A' && document.getElementById('MarcaInf3').disabled) {
            sigue = 'false';
            Swal.fire('Error!', 'Verifica captura de valor para Marcador inferior', 'error');
            return;
        }


        
            try {
                datos.forEach((valor, index) => {
                    let palabra;
                    if (index !== 'certificado_calidad_observaciones' && valor === "" ) { //esta parte es para que no haga la validacin de que este vacio 
                        sigue = "false";
                        const arreglo = index.split("_");
                        if (typeof arreglo[3] === "undefined") {
                            palabra = arreglo[2];
                        } else {
                            palabra = arreglo[2] + " " + arreglo[3];
                        }
                        throw "Verifica captura de valor para " + palabra; // Lanza la excepción solo si no es el campo de observaciones y está vacío
                    } else {
                        sigue = "true";
                    }
                });
            } catch (e) {
                Swal.fire("Error!", e, "error");
                return;
            }
```

intente esto pero no me funciona ya que muestra por segundos el N/A y se quita

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="MarcaInf3" name="MarcaInf3" maxlength="15" autocomplete="off" v-model="MarcaInf3" onkeypress="return validaNumericos(event)" value="<?php echo ($valor === "") ? 'N/A' : $valor; ?>">
```

espero me ayuden, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el valor del input MarcaInf3 se establece en N/A solo cuando el valor de la variable $valor es null o undefined. En todos los demás casos, el valor del input se establece en el valor de $valor.

Para que el valor del input MarcaInf3 se establezca en N/A cuando el valor de la variable $valor es "", puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MarcaInf3" name="MarcaInf3" maxlength="15" autocomplete="off" v-model="MarcaInf3" onkeypress="return validaNumericos(event)" value="<?php echo ($valor === "") ? 'N/A' : $valor; ?>" />
```

Este código usa el operador === para comparar el valor de la variable $valor con la cadena vacía. Si el valor de $valor es igual a la cadena vacía, el valor del input MarcaInf3 se establece en N/A. En todos los demás casos, el valor del input se establece en el valor de $valor.

Por ejemplo, si el valor de la variable $valor es "", el valor del input MarcaInf3 se establecerá en N/A. Si el valor de la variable $valor es "123", el valor del input MarcaInf3 se establecerá en 123.

También puedes usar el método trim() para eliminar los espacios en blanco del valor de la variable $valor antes de compararlo con la cadena vacía. Esto te permitirá que el valor del input MarcaInf3 se establezca en N/A cuando el valor de la variable $valor es una cadena vacía o una cadena con solo espacios en blanco.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="MarcaInf3" name="MarcaInf3" maxlength="15" autocomplete="off" v-model="MarcaInf3" onkeypress="return validaNumericos(event)" value="<?php echo ($valor === "") ? 'N/A' : trim($valor); ?>" />
```

Comment: muchas gracias, el problema es que cuando recargas la pagina muestra el N/A por unos segundos y luego desaparece